# How to generate random partitions of float number and each part has minimum value pMin?

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

for example:

I want to divide 33.38 into 5 parts, each part is equal or greater than 1.2:

2.71,3.3,18.7,1.56,7.11

function in pseudo code:

```
public static void printRandomPartition(float value,int numberOfParts,float pMin){
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    //it will print 2.71,3.3,18.7,1.56,7.11
    printRandomPartition(33.38,5,1.2);
}
```

another case:

divide 18.77 into 3 parts, each part is equal or greater than 3.2:

4.8,9.55,4.42

Of course the input and output may be ugly format float such as 3.82000000000003, it is just example only.

I searched some posts about it but seems most are about integers, and the method used in integers often uses array int myArray[n] (n is the integer to be divided), which is not useful to handle float. can anyone help?

Comment: You are aware that 3.82, for example, cannot be represented exactly in floating point?

Comment: I assume you want uniform distribution for each part? Note that you could remove 5*1.2 from 33.38 and ignore the "equal or greater than 1.2" constraint and simply add it back after each part has been extracted.

Answer (score 2):

pseudocode

```
function Divide(Sum, NParts, MinValue)
  //subtract minimal values to deal with corrected sum
  ASum = Sum - MinValue * NParts

  //generate uniform randoms (in any reasonable range), take their sum    
  BSum = 0
  for i = 0.. NParts - 1
     Part[i] = Random
     BSum = BSum + Part[i]

  //scale randoms to get right corrected sum, then add minimal value to get initial sum
  for i = 0.. NParts - 1
     Part[i] = Part[i] * ASum / BSum + MinValue
```